# How to install LAMP in linux without 'yum'

Tags: linux, lamp, yum

I need to install Pandora FMS monitoring tool, for that I need Apache, MYSQL server and Php alongwith pearl 5.8 support.
The problem is that we are not having open net access in our firm so cannot use the 'yum install' command.

---

Can any1 help how to install all these without taking the use of yum.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the source code and compile it. OR you could download .rpm files which are prebuilt and then transfer them onto machine

[Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24)

[PHP](http://php.net/downloads.php)

[MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Note, you will have to fetch all dependencies and this will suck unless you use YUM.

Comment: can you tell me how to use an .iso image for this purpose !?

Comment: @Manroop Please give me more details, however, something from [this page](http://lynxbites.blogspot.com/2009/10/create-yum-repository-from-iso-images.html) may be helpful.